# For Looping in Ionic 5/6 Angular (Beginner)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm very beginner to ionic angular, and I'm having trouble understanding how to handle looping in ionic angular. So I should declare an empty array? in my html page I needed to insert ionic input into an array but couldn't figure out how.

This is the coding that i am attempting to do:

in HTML

```
<div ngFor="let d of day; let index as i">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label></ion-label>
  <ion-list-header>
    <ion label> put your amount: </ion-label>
  </ion-list-header>
  <ion-item >
    <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
      <img src="assets/icon/document.png">
    </ion-thumbnail>
    <ion-input placeholder="1" [(ngModel)]="amount"></ion-input> //need to loop this 30 times
</ion-item>
</ion-item>
</div>
```

this is in my .ts file *I am not sure where to put the looping*

```
 day : any= [];
ionViewDidEnter() {  
    this.crud.getAllInfo();
    
    for(let i=0; i<31;i++){
      console.log(this.day[i]);
    }
    console.log(this.day)
  }
```

this is the interface

[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkqsT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your `ngFor` looks fine, I think the problem you are having is how you fill the `day` array, there are a couple of ways on how to store data into an array, you could try this way:

```js
...
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
days: number[] = []; // avoid using any as much as possible

 ngOnInit(): void {      
  for(let i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
    this.days.push(i);
  }
 }
}
```

And then, in your template HTML:

```html
<div *ngFor="let day of days; let i = index"> <!--if you need the index-->
 ...
 ...

 <ion-input [placeholder]="day" [(ngModel)]="amount"></ion-input>
</div>
```

For more information about `ngFor`, go [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#description)

Comment: It is not working, I tried your way ..

Comment: @wanaisa what error are you getting? start simple, just have the `div` with the `ngFor`, and within this div, have the `input` and see if it works...

Comment: @wanaisa, I updated my answer, I don't know when your `days` array is going to be filled, so I moved the logic into `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook, try it

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: @wanaisa I made a stackblitz demo, take a look, what is exactly that isn't working? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ubr42b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @andreas2142 I'm sorry for the delay, I have followed your code and it does showed the loop, but however my other issue is that when I type an amount in one of the input text fields, the rest of the fields automatically inject the same amount. do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of inputs and each one to save its value as the amount of that day you need to make some changes.

First thing, you only need one list with its header, and then you use the *ngFor loop inside of it to create as many ion-items as you want, and each one of them will have an input inside.

Second important thing is that the ngFor will need an array to loop, depending on what you want to do with the values in each input you can create an array of the desired length filled with empty values, an array of objects for example, and each one of them can have 'day' and 'amount' properties, etc.

Here you have simplified example (without labels, placeholders or stuff like that), as you can see, ngFor allows you to access each element of the array, and you can bind its value with ngModel. If each element of the array was an object you could access its properties with day.day, day.amount, etc.
Html:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-list-header>Header</ion-list-header>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let day of days; index as i; trackBy: trackByIndex">
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="days[i]"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  templateUrl: './hello.component.html',
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {
  public days: number[] = [];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.days = Array(30).fill(null);
  }

  public trackByIndex(index: number, obj: any): any {
    return index;
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13-gngubk?file=src/app/app.component.ts